# Qt Linguist - set translator for application

Tags: qt, qt4

how can i start creating a ts file that my application will use?

in the options of Linguist i can't create a new one with my own words and translation.... i can only translate a ts file that is allready exist.

Answer (score 5):

First, in your project, you need to write texts with tr() if you wanna translate them.
For example

```
QPushButton button(tr("Button"));
```

In your pro file, add

> TRANSLATIONS =  chinese.ts\ italian.ts

These files will be created automatically later.

Second, go to Qt Command Prompt. Go to your project directory from command prompt.
Then, write

> lupdate yourprojectname.pro

and press enter key. It will automatically create "ts" files `("chinese.ts" and "italian.ts")` for you.

After that, you need to open Qt Linguist and open your "ts" file. Add translation for your project. When you finish it, release it to get "qm" file.

When you want to translate your application, load the "qm" file.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QApplication a(argc, argv);

   QTranslator *translator = new QTranslator;
   translator->load("chinese.qm");

   a.installTranslator(translator);
}
```

Comment: thank you very much. i have another question: this way it does not recognize the translation command from the qml files, and i use qsTr()

Comment: Please read these documentation. I hope it will help you. 
http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qdeclarativei18n.html
http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/declarative-i18n.html

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be done by the qt command line tool [lupdate](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/linguist-manager.html#lupdate).

It will scan your code for strings you marked as translatable (tr() macro) and collect them in a *.ts file.

See the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/linguist-manager.html#lupdate) for more information.