# Internationalization on Qt 4.8

Tags: c++, qt, internationalization, qt4, qt4.8

I am trying to set a traslation to may app. I'm from Brazil so the app should be pt br and en-us, when coding I used english. I found this post on how to use QTranslator:

[Qt Linguist - set translator for application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290122/qt-linguist-set-traslator-for-application)

but when running the app on a pt-br system it shows up in english. Am I missing something?
P.S. didn't find the Q Command Prompt so I used the Menu Tools -> External -> Linguist -> Update Translation (lupdate).

Also have created the .qm file, here´s a piece of my code:

```
QApplication a(argc, argv);

QTranslator *trans = new QTranslator();

trans->load("C:/SVN/trunk/rcs/frameworkIdentity_ptbr.qm");

a.installTranslator(trans);

FIdMain w;
```

Comment: did you check return value of `load`?

Comment: also did you use [translate](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qtranslator.html#translate) function?

Comment: Yes I checked the return of load, it returns true, I used the tr function as in this example from Qt: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/linguist-hellotr.html

Comment: did you create translator before application's widgets?

Comment: definitly you're doing something wrong. Qt translators works preety well. Provide us reproducable sample. We can't get any conclusions from code you provided. Show us what is FIdMain w, tell us what part of application doesn't show translated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is pretty much what I do in my own application where translation is working (snipped below).

The problem is not in the snippets you've shown. As suggested in the comments it maybe that the widgets are created before the translator

```
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    QApplication app( argc, argv );

    QTranslator translator;
    if (  !Settings::value("monitor/languageFile").isNull() )
    {
        translator.load( Settings::value("monitor/languageFile").value<QString>() );
        app.installTranslator(&translator);
    }
    MainWindow mainWindow;
    mainWindow.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: The Translator is set before the main window, but still no changes, I'm browsing through Qt foruns looking for the solution.

Comment: Can only think that perhaps the translation file (.qm) doesn't contain the translated strings or perhaps you missed Q_OBJECT macro in a class. Try translating a string that comes from a .ui file first to see if it works, then you can narrow the problem.